# changing the voice in speech application commands

Tags: vba, speech

When using the speech VBA commands, can you change the voice away from the standard system voice.

this is the command im using.

```
Application.Speech.speak ("You have forgotten to enter the correct information")
```

Can you change the voice in  any way!

Having a lot of fun using this application command.

Comment: [This DDOE post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/05/10/the-talking-worksheet/) has some leads, but it seems like with Windows 7, at least, it's difficult to get more than one voice.

Comment: See also [Why does application Speech speak/read some numbers individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790329/why-does-application-speech-speak-read-some-numbers-individually-rather-than-put/48791412#48791412) and referred links at [Save SAPI Speech to a given file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285454/vba-save-sapi-speech-to-a-given-file-type)